# plotly Dash: Assigning indicator graph to dropdown values

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to assign an indicator graph to a dropdown list. The dropdown works when another graph type such as pie or bar is used, but I cannot get the indicator graph to change when an option is selected on the dropdown.
This is the working example for the pie chart I made

```
    @app.callback(
    Output(component_id='pie_graph2', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='pie_dropdown_percentage', component_property='value')]
)
def update_graph(year):
    piechart_qual2 =  px.bar(pie_melt_prevalence[pie_melt_prevalence['lau115nm'] == str(year)], x="namepie2", y="valuepie2",
                           title = "population level by percentage", animation_frame='year', hover_name="valuepie2", width=800,height=800,
                   
                  )
    return piechart_qual2
```

This is where I am struggling making the same dropdown work for the indicator graph

```
meanwage = df['weeklygrosspaymean'].tail(1).iloc[0].astype(float)

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='pie_graph3', component_property='figure'),
    [Input(component_id='pie_dropdown_percentage', component_property='value')]
)
def update_graph(year):
    fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode = "number+delta",
        value = meanwage,
        number = {'prefix': "£"},
        delta = {'position': "top", 'reference': 320},
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}))
    fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor = "lightgray")
    return fig
```

In the dashboard, the indicator graph does appear, it just doesn’t change when I select the dropdown
Any guidance would be hugely appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you mean, but your callback does NOT use your variable YEAR, you need to use it to alter your figure, or why do you even need a callback if you won't use it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32816152)